# Calculate the number of combinations of a sequence of numbers in a particular order

Tags: algorithms

I have a problem solving coding challenge when I have to calculate the number of combinations, numbers from **0** to **9**, with the length **n**, with **2** rules -

**-** The first number cannot be **0**

**-** Every other number can be **0** or must be divisible by the previous number (number **1** can not be used as divisor), for example **[5.0], [1,0]** or **[2,8], [4,8], [3,6]**

For example, if the length **n** were **2**, number of combinations would be **23 - [1,0]...[9,0] + [2,4], [2,6], [2,8], [3,6], [3,9], [4,8] + [2,2]...[9,9]**

---

The resulting response can be code in some programming language or a formula to calculate answer

Comment: if a digit is 0 what values an the next digit take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a neat way to solve this problem using graph theory.

First of all you need to decide the states and their transitions.

Example:-

```
2 ->[2,4,6,8]
3 ->[3,6,9] and so on.
```

Imagine each state to be a vertex in a  graph and each transition to be a directed edge.

Now construct the adjacency matrix.

In your case it may look like:-

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
[1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]]
```

Note that over here the `1s` represent that you can transition from the current state to that state.

Thus, if the `5th` element of the `3rd` row is `1` it means that you can go from `2`to`4`.

Finding all permissible combinations of length `n` is equivalent to finding all the walks of length `n` in this graph.

`(Adjacency_Matrix)^n` results in a matrix of the same dimension where (i,j) denotes number of unique walks of length `n` between vertex i and j.

Since first element cannot be `0`, you can sum up the values of this matrix for all `(i,j)` where `i!=0`. This would be your answer.

[Matrix Exponentiation](http://zobayer.blogspot.com/2010/11/matrix-exponentiation.html) takes O(d^3 log(n)) time. d-> DImension of matrix(10).

The DP approach would take too much time for n>10^4. Since this approach is `log(n)` it will perform better for large values of n.

Comment: Dynamic Programming approach works as well but I guess it would take O(n*d) time complexity where d->10. Depending upon the value of `n` you can choose what suits you well.

Comment: $0$ is also an outneighbor of each vertex.

Comment: you can modify the matrix acordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you solve the problem for $n=1$?
Can you deduce the answer for $k+1$, if you know the answer for $k$? 
(hint: you need an $n\times 10$ table, the $k$-th row devoted for problem size $k$, the columns for partial answers...)

ps: I think that the answer is $9+0+1+1+2+1+3+1+3+2=23$ for n=2 (and 125 for $n=3$)

```
0: 10,...,90
1: - 
2: 22
3: 33
4: 24,44
5: 55
6: 26,36,66
7: 77
8: 28,48,88
9: 39,99
```